# is it safe switching db on mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in my application I have a default database and other database I have to connect to in function of client's  requests , since with mongoose in node as far as I understood: there is a pool of connections application wide, if I change database, it is changed for all the subsequent requests, I think it could cause some problems, what is the best way to switch Database with mongoose?

Comment: Are you wanting both databases to be live, or is it that there are documents in the default database that you would like in the 'other' database?

Comment: the default database should be always alive, the second may change, my users must be able to select it.

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose 3.7.1 (unstable) supports [switching databases](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.7-%28unstable%29-Release-Notes#connection-pool-sharing).

Otherwise you'll need to create separate connection instances for each database.